# Android FrameLayout best solution

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

i have simple LinearLayout as container and i'd like to show severals FrameLayouts inside. It should looks like below but id but it needs to be dynamically. The point is that number of framelayout that i will need, will be return from sql response. I found some similar questions but i need to treat my framelayouts as surfaces (with elevation, margin...). When i run app it should looks like below example. Maybe somebody know best method to achieve this.
[image]

Comment: Why FrameLayout and not CardView? Is there a real need of so much FrameLayouts?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the RecyclerView. You can add the children as CardView, you can control elevation and stuff.

PS: Next time you should research a bit. I bet you could find the answer faster than waiting for someone to give it to you

Comment: Google Udacity inspire me to use FrameLayout https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud862/lessons/4755536308/concepts/47545437130923 anyway thanks for help